# How to prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}{|\sin n|}$ doesn't exist

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

How to prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}{|\sin n|}$ doesn't exist.
$n\in\mathbb N$

Any hint?

Comment: this limit doesn't exist

Comment: Sorry, I've made a mistake in the tittle. Now it should be ok.

Comment: Hint: Each interval $[n\pi/2-1/2,n\pi/2+1/2]$ contains an integer.

Comment: $|\sin n| = |\sin 2\pi\cdot\frac{n}{2\pi}|$ and the fractional parts $\{n/2\pi\}$ is everywhere danse in $(0,1)$ due to irrationality of $1/2\pi$.

Comment: A sequence *is* a function with a domain of the Natural numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do we mean a limit exist? We should have a number $l\in R$ (or $R\cup\{\infty\}\cup\{-\infty\})$ such that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}| |\sin n|-l|=0\,\,\,\, \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(1)$$
That is, for any subsequence of $(n)$ the equation $(1)$ should hole.

Now, let us choose $n_k\in[2k\pi-\pi/6,2k\pi +\pi/6]$ be an integer, then we have
$$ \limsup_{k\to\infty}|\sin n_k|\leq \frac{1}{2} $$
However, if we choose $n_k\in [2k\pi+\pi/4,2k/pi+3\pi/4]$ be an integer (choose when you can), then
$$ \liminf_{k\to\infty}|\sin n_k|\geq \sqrt{2}/2 $$

Hence the limit does not exist.

Note that we are keep choose an subsequence of sequence $(n)$. The subsequence, indexed by $k$, does not need exists for each $k$,

Comment: The values of $n$ you are choosing here are not integers

Comment: Now the answer should be ok.

Answer (score 2):

For $x \in \left[2k\pi + \frac{\pi}{6} , 2k\pi + \frac{5\pi}{6}\right]$ for integer $k$, you have $\sin(x) \ge \frac12$.

For $x \in \left[2k\pi + \frac{7\pi}{6} , 2k\pi + \frac{11\pi}{6}\right]$ for integer $k$, you have $\sin(x) \le -\frac12$.

So for every $7(\gt 2\pi)$ consecutive integers you have at least two with $\sin(n) \ge \frac{1}{2}$ and at least two with $\sin(n) \le -\frac{1}{2}$, since $\frac{5\pi}{6}-\frac{\pi}{6}=\frac{11\pi}{6}-\frac{7\pi}{6}\gt 2$.

So $\sin(n)$ does not converge.

Answer (score 2):

Assume there is a limit $L$. This means given any $\epsilon > 0$, eventually we have
$$\vert \sin(n) - L \vert  < \epsilon \implies \sin(n) - \epsilon < L < \sin(n) + \epsilon$$

To be specific, let us pick $\epsilon = 1/4$.

Now pick $n  \in (2m \pi - \pi/2,2m \pi -\pi/6)$. This is possible since the interval length is $\pi/3>1$. We have $\sin(n) < -1/2$. There exists infinitely many $n$'s and hence $L < -1/4$.

Now pick $n  \in (2m \pi + \pi/6,2m \pi +\pi/2)$. This is possible since the interval length is $\pi/3>1$. We have $\sin(n) > 1/2$. There exists infinitely many $n$'s and hence $L>1/4$.

Hence, no such $L$ exists.

Comment: The original function is the absolute value of sin, please fix your answer for the function asked.